# SQL Statement definition, implemented correctly, still says it's beans

Tags: java, sql

I am new here but I need help with something.

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class testConnection {
    private ConfigurationManager  cmi;
    private Statement stmt ; 

    public testConnection() {
        cmi = new ConfigurationManager();
    }

    public void test() throws SQLException{
        cmi.openConnection();
        stmt = cmi.createStatement();
    }
}
```

I know this piece of code is not finished but it gives me error on `"stmt = cmi.createStatement();"`. It says it found beans but I already defined it as SQL and imported the SQL statement so I don't really get it. I have another application and I did it the same way but there it worked.

Here is the text of the error(compilation):

```
**: incompatible types
found   : java.beans.Statement
required: java.sql.Statement
        stmt = cmi.createStatement();
1 error**
```

Comment: You should edit your question and add the error too. Also try to reformulate "it ses it found beans but i already defined it as sql and imported the sql statement".

Comment: Your question is not clear. Paste the exact exception stack trace here

Comment: It sounds like `cmi.createStatement()` is returning an instance of the `java.beans.Statement` class, whereas you're expecting it to return `java.sql.Statement`.

Comment: For the love of Cthulhu, write intelligible English next time you post a question.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the issue is in your ConfigurationManager. since it's returning  a `java.beans.Statement` instead of a `java.sql.Statement` object.

Comment: Thenks alot, hehe nex time i should look more closely